# How can you check the message? node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot

I am writing to the bot's telegram, how can you make it ignore such messages?
" Manager", " Contracts", " Notifications"
First comes some kind of emoticon and then text.
I tried to do through regex
I am using the library **node-telegram-bot-api**

```
bot.onText(/(.+)/, (msg, match) => {
  if ((/^([/^[a-zA-Z]*$/]*)$/.test(msg.text))) {
      return;
  }
)}
```

Comment: which part of your code is failing? Does the general structure of the onText event handler work well but you're just missing the correct regex?

Comment: @lucasreta  Hi, the whole application is working, I just don't know how to filter messages of this kind " Manager" and I haven't come up with anything other than a regular expression, and even it doesn't work (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter all (or at least many) emojis and phrases following the given format using this regular expression:

```js
if( /^(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff]) ([A-Za-z])\w+/.test(msg.text))) {
  return;
}
```

Brief rundown of our regex:

We validate that the beginning of the string matches our first capturing group, with contains a check for common emoji characters and ranges ([source](https://ihateregex.io/expr/emoji/)):

```
^(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])
```

We check that our emoji is followed by a space and a word:

```
 ([A-Za-z])\w+
```

**Edit:** Initially I added a `.*` at the end of our regex, removed it now because it's redundant for current purposes.